# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'D' of undefined

Tags: javascript

I tried to practice the task-scheduling problem,but I got some javascript code that gives this error

> script2.js:21 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'D' of undefined(…)

Code:

```
var P = [100, 10, 15, 27, 36, 58, 62, 43, 52, 65];
var D = [3, 2, 5, 5, 4, 2, 2, 4, 3, 4]
var list = [];
for(var j in P){
    list.push({'P':P[j],'D':D[j]});
}

list.sort(function(a,b){
    return((a.P>b.P)? -1 :((a.P == b.P) ? 0:1));
});

for(var k = 0 ;k<list.length;k++){
    P[k] = list[k].P;
    D[k] = list[k].D;
}
```

The `list[k].D` here still works.

```
var new_list =new Array(P.length);
new_list[0] = list[0];
for(var j  = 1;j<=P.length;j++){
    if(list[j].D>list[j-1].D){
        new_list[j] = list[j];

    }
    else if(list[j-1].D<list[j-1].D){
        new_list.unshift = list[j];
        }
    }
```

I got a TypeError about

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'D' of undefined

Why is it wrong??

Comment: Because at some point, an undefined object is making its way into your list.

Comment: `new_list.unshift = list[j];` is assigning a value to the `unshift` property on `new_list`. If you wanted to *call* `unshift`, you'd use `()`.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I see ! I was not very practied! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

`for(var j = 1; j <= P.length; j++)` will cause the index `j` to reach `P.length` which is not there. Hence, while you do `list[j].D` there is no `D` for undefined. You should either have a strict inequality there or have `P.length - 1`.

Comment: Please mark the answer if you think it solved your problem! :)